# Make a different connection to different database and put it into the list

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to make a separate connection for each database as `JDBC URL's` are different for them and store those different connections in an Array.

In my below code, `tableList` is the map which will contain table Names and there properties and should look something like this.

```
 ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> tableList
```

Sample Example-

`{table1={DRIVER=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, PASSWORD=stage_cs_user, URL=jdbc_url, SUFFIX=xt1, SQL=sql, USER=user}, table2={DRIVER=driver_name, PASSWORD=pass, URL=jdbc_url2, SUFFIX=xt2, SQL=sql2, USER=user}}`

Now that means I need to make two database connections within `each thread` in a run method as JDBC url's are different for each table. So I have made Connection in my code as list here and callableStatement also, and depending on tableList size it will make the connection.

Like if we have only one table, then it will make only one connection, if we have two tables, then it will make two connections.

Something like `dbConnection[0]`, `dbConnection[1]`  etc.

And for each table, I am calling `getRequiredMethods(suffix)`. So I need to make this as the list also. Because if we have two tables, then it will be having methods for two tables in a list.

Below is my code, I am not sure, how to loop that `tableList` map in the run method and make a new connection and assign it as `dbConenction[0]` and `dbConnection[1]` depending on the `tableList size` and making sure all the thread safety issues here.

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    private Connection[] dbConnection = null;
    private CallableStatement[] callableStatement = null;


    public Task(ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> tableList) {
        this.tableLists = tableList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            for(loop around lableList map) {

 /* Make a connection to database and assign it as dbConnection[0], 
   dbConnection[1] and callableStatement[0] etc.
  */        
            dbConnection = getDBConnection(url, username, password, driver);
            callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(sql);

            ArrayList<Method> methods = getRequiredMethods(suffix);
            }

        }   

    }

    private ArrayList<Method> getRequiredMethods(String suffix) {

        Class<ConstantsTest> consClass = ConstantsTest.class;
        Method[] methods = consClass.getDeclaredMethods();
        ArrayList<Method> requiredMethods = new ArrayList<Method>();
        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            String sName = methods[i].getName();
            if (sName.endsWith(suffix)) {
                requiredMethods.add(methods[i]);
            }
        }
        return requiredMethods;
    }
```

Can anyone help me out here?

**Updated Code:-**

I made some progress here- I wrote the below code in  my run method-

```
public void run() {

        ArrayList<Method> methods[];

        for( int i=0; i<tableLists.size(); i++) {

            dbConnection[i] = getDBConnection(tableLists.get(i).get("URL"), tableLists.get(i).get("USERNAME"), tableLists.get(i).get("PASSWORD"), tableLists.get(i).get("DRIVER"));
            callableStatement[i] = dbConnection[i].prepareCall(tableLists.get(i).get("SQL"));

            methods[i] = getRequiredMethods(tableLists.get(i).get("SUFFIX"));
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are using multiple threads and that each thread has to be able to access two separate database connections.

The usual way to deal with this is not to write your own code, but to use connection pooling: an underlying set of actual database sockets are managed by some code and you just get lightweight references to them that can be closed and returned to the pool. Two java packages that I would recommend for this are [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) and [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/). You would then create a pool of connections for database 1 and database 2.

This way, each thread need only request a connection from pool 1 or pool 2 (depending on the database it needs), do whatever it wants to do, and then `close()` the connection when done. The pool will automatically create a number of actual sockets depending on load and will manage all the synchronization between threads for you.

Comment: Yeah. I have already written my code. It will take some time to redesign everything to start using BoneCP or C3P0 for that. I wanted to stick my current code and improve it slightly.

Comment: In my humble opinion, your existing work is a sunk cost. One time, I erased thousands of lines of code after finding an existing package that did the same job but better. It would only take a few new lines to switch over, but you will have to get over the pain of erasing your existing work. :)